# The Matrix of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: P_1(R) → P_2(R)$ be a linear map defined by $T p(t) = tp(t) + p(0)$. Let
$\{t + 1, t − 1\}, \{t^2 + 1, t − 1,t + 1\}$ be bases of $P_1(R)$ and $P_2(R)$ respectively. Find the matrix of the map T.

Here is my attempt:

$\{t^2 + 1, t − 1,t + 1\}$ is a basis of $P_2(R)$, then

$(t^2 +1) = t(t^2 +1) + 0 = t^3 + t + 0 $

$(t - 1) = t(t-1) + 0 = t^2 - t + 0 $

$(t + 1) = t(t+1) + 0 = t^2 + t + 0 $

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 &  1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$

I might be wrong, so any inputs are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your notation is confusing.  For example, you should write
$$
T[(t^2 +1)] = t(t^2 +1) + 0 = t^3 + t + 0
$$
or perhaps
$$
(t^2 +1) \mapsto t(t^2 +1) + 0 = t^3 + t + 0
$$
Note, however, that neither of these are correct, anyway.  In this case, $p(0) = 1$.

Comment: What about my matrix? is it right or wrong? any opinion?

Comment: It's wrong.  Posting an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is incorrect.  To get you started on the right road:
$$
T((1,0)_{B_1}) =
T[(t +1)] = t(t + 1) + 1 = t^2 + t + 1 
\\= (t^2 + 1) + \frac 12(t-1) + \frac 12 (t+1) = (1,1/2,1/2)_{B_2}
$$
So, the first column of your matrix should be $\pmatrix{1\\1/2\\1/2}$